# Lua attempt to index global 'self' error (GMod Lua script)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I have been getting the following error with this section of code:

```
[ERROR] lua/entities/cook/init.lua:58: attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)1. cooked - lua/entities/cook/init.lua:58
```

The function starts at line 57, and when I remove line 58 `(local Pos = self.Entity:GetPos()` , it just gives the same error message for line 61.

```
function cooked()
    local Pos = self.Entity:GetPos()
    local roll = math.random(1, 5);
        if roll == 5 then
        self.Entity:EmitSound("phx/explode06.wav")
        self.Entity:Remove()
        else
        local createfood = ents.Create("food")
        createfood:SetPos(Pos + Vector(0,10,100)) 
        createfood:Spawn()
        self:SendLua("GAMEMODE:AddNotify(\"You finish cooking the food and package the product!\", NOTIFY_GENERIC, 4)")
        end
end
```

Comment: why exactly did you accept Maze's answer but not Tom's, which is not only correct but also explaining why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what `self` should be. The error says it's a global, which is consistent with the code you have shown.

But, `self` is almost exclusively used as a formal parameter to a function and an implicit one at that.

When `self` is implicit, the function is called a method because the *intent* is for it to access fields in a table passed into `self`. The method value is almost always held by a field in the same table (or at least, available as such via metamethods).

**The colon syntax in a function definition creates a method.**

If `cooked` was a method then it would make sense for it to access `self`. But `cooked` is a global.

You might have meant:

```
function sometable:cooked()
-- ...
-- self is an implicit formal parameter
-- ...
end
```

How to read the Lua statement above:

1. access sometable as a table
2. assign its "cooked" field the function value created by the function definition.

(The function definition is compiled from the method syntax, so in the body, `self` is the first formal parameter, which is implicit.)

The method could be called like:

```
sometable:cooked() -- passes sometable as self
```

**The colon syntax in a field function call is a method call.**

How to read the Lua statement above:

1. access sometable as a table,
2. index its "cooked" field,
3. call its value as a function, passing sometable as the first parameter,
4. discard the result list.

---

Oddities:

- The syntax for methods is just "syntactic sugar." Methods values are no different than other function values:

  - A function created from a function definition using the any syntax can be called using any function call syntax.

    - A method need not be called using the method call syntax.
    - A non-method can be called using the method call syntax.
- `self` is not reserved so it can be used as any identifier is.

Answer (score 1):

Self is nil, so how do you call cooked()?
It has to be self.cooked(self) or self:cooked(), where self is the table you want to use as self in your function.

Comment: actually, the function must also be defined as `function sometable:cooked()` or `function sometable.cooked(self)`